Why is the svg image cropped?
I wanted to make a website for the first time, but it's too hard
https://mapsvg.com/maps/world
Here I downloaded a world map.I set the width: 100% height: auto, but why is the map cropped? I want to know the reason.
and also I wonder why the background color doesn't fill up
I put background color in body tag in css file, but it was still white. I put svg in inline.

Please add your minimal example to the question. If it's just a link and you fix it after getting an answer the question wrong be much use to anyone else.

Do you have a viewBox attribute for the svg element?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is a lack of information in your question. But I can make an educated guess at what your problem is.
The most likely reason you are having problems is that you haven't given the browser enough information on how to scale the map.  In order to scale the SVG, the browser needs to know what the extent of the content in the SVG is.  It does that by using the SVG attribute viewBox.  A width and height by themselves is not enough.  Unfortunately, your SVG does not have a viewBox defined. So the browser will not scale it.  It will just draw it at 1:1 scale. Meaning that most of the map may be off the screen because the map default size is 1009.6727 x 665.96301 (pixels).
The solution is to give the SVG a viewBox attribute.  You can just use the existing width and height values for that. In my example, I've just rounded them up to the nearest whole number:
<svg ... viewBox="0 0 1010 666"...>



body {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
<svg
   xmlns:mapsvg="http://mapsvg.com"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   mapsvg:geoViewBox="-169.110266 83.600842 190.486279 -58.508473"
   width="1009.6727"
   height="665.96301"
   viewBox="0 0 1010 666">

  <path
 d="m 431.27375,213.3184 0.322,0.026 0.526,-0.239 0.22,-0.157 0.541,-0.545 0.319,-0.152 0.493,0.038 0.237,-0.038 0.006,0.053 -0.303,0.221 -0.242,0.076 -0.348,0.329 -0.331,0.74 -0.245,0.362 0.002,0.161 0.298,0.285 0.327,0.161 0.3,-0.146 0.131,0.057 0.118,0.211 0.067,0.209 0.015,0.207 -0.054,0.432 -0.18,0.433 -0.244,0.362 0.034,0.114 0.196,0.058 0.929,-0.234 0.097,0.017 0.053,0.117 0.011,0.216 0.051,0.195 0.092,0.175 -0.029,0.178 -0.407,0.563 0.481,-0.354 0.379,-0.1 0.65,0.178 0.266,0.204 0.155,0.359 0.225,-0.119 0.098,0.007 0.147,0.204 0.005,0.218 -0.108,0.309 -0.037,0.286 -0.113,0.117 -0.211,0.085 -0.06,0.095 0.093,0.217 0.137,0.212 0.194,0.009 0.035,0.098 0.004,0.117 -0.026,0.138 -0.063,0.094 -0.101,0.052 -0.133,0.151 0.488,0.33 0.062,0.123 0.007,0.179 -0.038,0.197 -0.083,0.214 -0.147,0.126 -0.352,0.021 -0.216,0.139 0.074,0.23 -0.006,0.291 -0.065,0.343 -0.277,0.517 -0.26,0.275 -0.255,0.178 -0.454,-0.063 -0.247,-0.137 0.027,0.445 -0.252,0.273 0.047,0.228 0.088,0.116 -0.043,0.292 -0.12,0.289 -0.201,0.312 -0.228,0.195 -0.453,0.235 -0.387,0.389 -0.264,0.154 -0.658,-0.007 -0.671,0.25 -0.948,0.526 -0.639,0.42 -0.493,0.475 -0.651,0.772 -0.483,0.324 -0.279,0.087 -0.543,0.069 -0.455,0.209 -1.511,0.39 -0.511,0.213 -0.066,0.193 -0.212,0.291 -0.013,0.105 0.092,0.081 0.018,0.105 -0.187,0.343 -0.374,0.247 -0.176,-0.004 -0.214,-0.213 -0.093,0.008 -0.037,0.033 -0.002,0.066 0.123,0.256 -0.226,0.118 -0.984,0.298 -1.675,-0.22 -0.663,-0.229 -0.819,-0.366 -0.487,-0.097 -0.691,-0.024 -0.568,-0.512 -0.263,-0.317 -0.021,-0.132 0.03,-0.151 0.059,-0.103 0.088,-0.055 0.187,-0.006 0.025,-0.045 -0.143,-0.255 -0.137,0.083 -0.365,0.36 -0.163,-0.013 -0.214,-0.18 -0.008,-0.175 -0.417,-0.067 -0.363,-0.219 -0.361,-0.315 -0.054,-0.12 0.174,-0.177 -0.034,-0.034 -0.131,-0.03 -0.263,0.058 -0.397,0.399 -0.171,0.092 -2.593,0.093 -0.658,0.041 -0.127,0.061 -0.114,-0.259 -0.102,-0.58 -0.038,-0.383 0.026,-0.186 0.091,-0.223 0.141,0.038 0.134,0.177 0.122,0.251 0.139,0.122 0.905,-0.306 0.368,-0.206 0.156,-0.195 0.184,-0.334 0.195,-0.171 0.093,-0.161 0.183,-0.513 0.126,-0.238 0.152,-0.177 0.176,-0.114 0.4,-0.081 -0.263,-0.121 -0.252,0 -0.854,0.543 -0.287,0 0.012,-0.085 0.121,-0.153 0.294,-0.265 -0.202,-0.02 -0.077,-0.12 -0.009,-0.253 0.15,-0.409 0.696,-0.54 0.241,-0.08 0.073,-0.107 -0.091,-0.087 -0.146,-0.053 -0.7,0.557 -0.51,0.192 -0.151,-0.037 -0.264,-0.215 -0.085,-0.097 -0.114,-0.247 0.014,-0.149 0.242,-0.438 -0.039,-0.085 -0.167,-0.043 -0.449,-0.404 -0.71,0.041 -1.759,-0.235 -0.364,0.1 -0.599,0.347 -0.362,0.114 -0.167,-0.075 -0.152,-0.184 -0.138,-0.247 -0.124,-0.313 0.053,-0.217 0.232,-0.124 0.17,-0.059 0.479,0.075 0.584,-0.219 0.372,-0.046 0.107,-0.035 0.219,-0.233 0.108,-0.059 0.168,0.082 0.082,0.158 0.587,-0.246 0.202,-0.123 0.023,-0.077 0.088,-0.088 0.292,0.133 0.237,0.004 0.295,-0.092 0.522,-0.04 1.169,-0.021 0.175,-0.201 0.082,-0.178 0.103,-0.453 -0.046,-0.093 -0.729,0.417 -0.167,-0.007 -0.845,-0.221 -0.305,-0.25 0.1,-0.201 0.448,-0.434 0.462,-0.348 0.68,-0.378 0.159,-0.147 0.017,-0.175 -0.454,-0.311 -0.857,0.086 -0.22,-0.369 -0.713,-0.219 -0.474,0.137 -0.252,-0.224 -0.616,0.31 -1.354,0.447 -0.539,0.309 -0.29,0.103 -0.334,-0.252 -0.576,-0.285 -0.648,-0.089 -0.058,-0.168 0.378,-0.515 0.259,-0.094 0.26,0.048 0.497,0.359 0.343,0.113 -0.43,-0.528 0.011,-0.203 -0.033,-0.305 -0.132,-0.131 -0.132,-0.338 0.054,-0.114 0.169,-0.041 0.346,0.115 0.823,0.586 0.404,-0.104 0.221,-0.216 0.303,-0.16 -0.086,-0.083 -0.711,-0.01 -0.381,-0.12 -0.192,-0.172 -0.167,-0.293 0.059,-0.135 0.198,-0.108 0.607,0.032 -0.4,-0.511 -0.278,-0.294 -0.03,-0.142 0.019,-0.178 0.037,-0.12 0.057,-0.06 0.696,0.3 0.153,0.012 -0.141,-0.193 -0.306,-0.285 -0.013,-0.107 0.129,-0.087 0.063,-0.163 0.006,-0.134 0.211,-0.116 0.214,-0.005 0.215,0.106 0.666,0.556 0.095,0.156 0.032,0.205 -0.033,0.255 0.028,0.102 0.26,-0.087 0.208,0.107 0.103,-0.029 0.259,-0.383 0.178,0.091 0.107,0.179 0.034,0.162 0.016,0.222 -0.046,0.462 0.012,0.065 0.181,-0.261 0.308,-0.02 0.04,-0.131 0.009,-0.486 -0.025,-0.412 -0.034,-0.084 -1.014,-0.572 -0.176,-0.136 -0.221,-0.282 0.045,-0.142 0.198,-0.127 0.297,-0.051 0.691,0.007 0.07,-0.06 -0.134,-0.149 -0.319,-0.096 -0.075,-0.087 -0.038,-0.166 -0.379,0.091 -0.423,0.004 -0.407,-0.102 -0.008,-0.129 0.16,-0.19 0.333,-0.315 0.154,-0.079 0.465,0.055 0.461,-0.089 0.374,0.108 0.297,0.312 0.421,0.548 0.57,0.349 0.053,0.11 0.303,0.285 0.604,0.766 0.613,0.443 0.028,0.113 -0.101,0.132 -0.236,0.155 0.054,0.085 0.308,0.113 0.222,0.298 0.015,0.13 -0.201,0.92 -0.107,0.195 -0.122,0.103 -0.566,-0.173 0.134,0.292 0.405,0.31 0.091,0.173 -0.06,0.17 0.044,0.039 0.148,-0.091 0.062,0.096 -0.026,0.283 -0.063,0.235 -0.101,0.186 0.03,0.081 0.158,-0.025 0.148,0.048 0.232,0.257 0.188,0.783 0.093,0.252 0.068,-0.224 0.084,-0.571 0.079,-0.292 0.075,-0.013 0.064,-0.096 0.054,-0.18 0.11,-0.636 0.38,-0.483 0.181,-0.149 0.171,-0.032 0.082,0.06 0.285,0.507 0.173,0.085 0.088,-0.027 0.122,-0.345 0.154,-0.662 0.035,-0.742 -0.083,-0.823 0.048,-0.59 0.181,-0.353 0.237,-0.109 0.295,0.136 0.215,0.216 0.424,0.82 0.343,0.429 0.294,0.458 0.152,0.149 0.292,0.075 0.078,-0.03 0.052,-0.105 0.027,-0.182 -0.063,-1.171 0.082,-0.365 0.124,-0.261 0.526,-0.153 0.287,-0.164 0.279,-0.269 0.231,-0.145 0.184,-0.019 0.191,0.105 0.201,0.229 0.312,0.446 0.393,0.737 0.5,0.548 0.261,0.868 0.056,0.146 0.062,0.017 0.066,-0.113 0.042,-0.159 0.012,-0.386 -0.14,-0.512 -0.467,-1.297 -0.008,-0.247 0.059,-0.198 0.329,-0.022 0.766,0.12 0.244,0.202 0.521,0.794 0.146,0.192 0.089,0.048 0.033,-0.096 0.202,-0.147 0.139,-0.178 0.233,-0.438 0.509,-0.79 0.106,-0.023 0.148,0.062 0.261,0.207 0.124,0.166 0.245,0.126 0.251,-0.044 0.347,-0.277 0.393,-0.17 0.134,-0.393 0.025,-0.18 -0.316,-1.177 0.133,-0.242 0.685,-0.293 0.599,-0.023 0.142,0.081 0.377,0.575 0.256,0.288 0.129,0.231 0.031,0.509 0.155,0.187 z"
 title="Iceland"
 id="IS" />
  <path
     d="m 990.79075,598.9554 -0.101,0.101 -0.172,-0.005 -0.301,0.395 0.019,-0.295 -0.09,-0.115 -0.258,0.027 -0.049,0.065 0.173,0.078 0.038,0.043 -0.165,0.171 0.172,0.367 0.15,-0.013 0.146,0.287 -10e-4,0.09 -0.334,0.111 -0.176,0.155 -0.157,-0.006 -0.074,-0.03 -0.088,-0.277 -0.007,-0.116 0.193,-0.203 0.109,-0.207 -0.088,-0.19 -0.223,-0.123 -0.486,0.056 -0.112,-0.041 0.243,-0.256 0.264,0.028 0.284,-0.184 1.091,0.087 z m 0.003,2.262 -0.124,0.034 0.018,-0.223 -0.042,-0.144 0.21,-0.047 0.09,0.171 -0.152,0.209 z m -29.619,-34.16 0.042,0.156 0.155,-0.111 0.116,-0.175 0.187,-0.178 -0.025,0.287 0.096,0.063 0.62,0.2 0.128,0.167 0.132,0.048 0.074,-0.094 0.088,-0.051 0.224,0.105 0.506,0.292 0.042,0.101 -0.026,0.15 0.025,0.159 0.069,0.127 0.168,0.029 0.224,-0.188 0.105,-0.023 0.148,0.267 0.056,0.151 -0.023,-0.005 0.097,0.15 0.128,0.148 0.221,0.439 -0.033,0.154 -0.065,0.139 0.203,0.407 -0.133,0.028 -0.399,-0.069 0.013,0.082 0.233,0.299 0.196,0.423 0.157,0.255 0.554,0.793 -0.083,0.282 0.013,0.187 -0.071,0.161 0.189,0.422 -0.118,0.131 -0.078,0.433 -0.086,0.076 0.011,0.158 0.224,0.042 0.135,0.067 0.116,0.129 0.072,-0.155 0.098,-0.042 0.267,0.207 0.556,0.207 0.153,0.077 0.075,0.167 0.057,0.404 0.108,0.178 0.213,0.034 0.229,-0.054 0.072,-0.147 -0.046,-0.396 -0.165,-0.632 -0.001,-0.205 0.023,-0.206 -0.038,-0.204 -0.083,-0.192 -0.089,-0.147 -0.114,-0.124 0.04,-0.193 0.171,-0.087 0.104,0.163 0.085,0.197 0.431,0.584 0.255,-0.041 0.023,0.242 0.173,0.246 0.096,0.289 0.126,0.865 0.193,0.817 0.35,0.356 0.041,0.171 -0.213,-0.088 -0.065,0.051 0.022,0.086 0.197,0.157 0.232,0.077 0.146,-0.011 0.137,0.057 0.907,0.534 0.436,0.208 1.1,0.341 0.314,0.027 0.174,-0.009 0.329,-0.118 0.295,-0.212 0.255,-0.317 0.22,-0.361 0.239,-0.175 0.271,-0.138 0.137,-0.128 0.144,-0.091 0.737,0.042 0.249,0.182 0.323,0.146 0.169,0.114 -0.057,0.232 -0.193,0.342 -0.148,0.375 -0.132,0.854 -0.089,0.866 -0.134,0.383 -0.244,0.295 -0.27,0.216 -0.305,0.102 -0.124,0.495 -0.061,0.581 0.018,0.146 0.098,0.116 0.04,0.173 -0.16,0.35 -0.093,-0.051 -0.132,-0.292 -0.119,-0.122 -0.366,-0.091 -0.373,-0.042 -0.323,0.026 -0.312,0.125 -0.471,0.253 -0.146,0.128 -0.128,0.163 -0.216,0.364 -0.052,0.446 0.01,0.234 0.077,0.181 0.401,0.247 -0.398,0.864 -0.353,0.902 -0.2,0.258 -0.23,0.239 -0.217,0.545 -0.379,0.47 -0.256,0.36 -0.2,0.374 -0.175,0.398 -0.373,0.563 -0.165,0.373 -0.216,0.311 -0.402,0.397 -0.428,0.341 -0.674,0.472 -0.188,0.156 -0.198,0.115 -0.246,-0.135 -0.049,-0.147 -0.059,-0.323 -0.054,-0.118 -0.313,-0.098 -0.415,0.156 -0.069,-0.033 -0.018,-0.074 0,-0.469 0.07,-0.132 -0.097,-0.073 -0.096,0.029 -0.033,0.12 0.061,0.104 -0.236,0.129 -0.246,0.003 -0.074,-0.051 -0.021,-0.086 0.06,-0.142 0.079,-0.125 0.457,-0.59 0.475,-0.781 0.409,-0.834 0.106,-0.428 0.15,-0.792 -0.123,-0.33 -0.152,-0.309 -0.411,-0.594 -0.549,-0.335 -0.355,-0.047 -0.336,-0.125 -0.316,-0.283 -0.288,-0.333 -0.571,-0.273 -0.602,-0.214 -0.343,-0.302 -0.082,-0.179 -0.054,-0.208 0.008,-0.193 0.043,-0.196 0.068,-0.15 0.107,-0.109 0.637,-0.389 0.675,-0.216 0.124,0.004 0.119,-0.035 0.169,-0.132 0.302,-0.302 0.088,-0.203 0.06,-0.644 0.097,-0.632 0.175,-0.723 0.264,-0.447 0.086,-0.274 -0.107,-0.451 0.099,-0.165 0.12,-0.1 0.136,-0.058 -0.23,-0.422 -0.271,-0.637 -0.057,-0.197 0.041,-0.195 0.066,-0.191 -0.169,-0.048 -0.098,-0.183 -0.243,-0.615 0.066,-0.098 0.141,0.066 0.209,0.443 0.034,-0.228 0.16,-0.141 0.17,-0.073 0.182,-0.016 -0.412,-0.494 -0.138,0.02 -0.182,0.079 -0.187,0.048 -0.183,-0.043 -0.171,-0.109 -0.088,-0.208 -0.107,-0.399 -0.067,-0.147 -0.542,-0.813 0.159,-0.026 0.438,0.407 0.085,-0.13 0.063,-0.187 -0.021,-0.208 -0.104,-0.158 -0.155,-0.102 -0.003,-0.185 0.118,-0.169 -0.007,-0.118 -0.251,-0.241 -0.1,-0.026 -0.045,0.112 0.072,0.167 -0.067,0.019 -0.609,-0.438 -0.188,-0.352 -0.154,-0.386 -0.016,0.157 0.023,0.221 0.241,0.443 0.391,0.496 0.067,0.132 -0.058,0.171 -0.136,0.049 -0.12,-0.108 -0.179,-0.425 -0.129,-0.212 -1.495,-2.184 0.191,-0.287 0.296,-0.242 0.068,-0.107 0.045,-0.131 -0.125,-0.022 -0.112,0.06 -0.128,0.111 -0.117,0.126 -0.148,0.281 -0.07,0.065 -0.175,-0.195 -0.067,-0.12 0.003,-0.144 -0.047,-0.091 -0.13,-0.029 -0.191,-0.286 -0.121,-0.146 0.202,-0.279 0.005,-0.367 -0.206,-0.384 -0.246,-0.353 -0.474,-0.569 -0.435,-0.601 0.471,-0.076 0.478,-0.013 -0.225,0.36 0.102,0.208 0.152,0.176 0.328,0.54 0.028,0.156 0.166,0.158 0.08,0.121 z m 6.38,4.621 0.022,0.189 -0.215,-0.067 -0.084,-0.143 -0.241,-0.148 -0.035,-0.044 -0.027,-0.287 0.127,-0.139 0.021,-0.059 0.056,-0.023 0.099,0.151 0.191,0.215 0.086,0.355 z m -6.813,17.94 0.323,0.018 0.301,-0.272 0.308,-0.221 0.323,-0.183 0.492,-0.419 0.129,-0.062 0.319,-0.08 0.139,-0.099 0.155,-0.023 -0.14,0.248 -0.176,0.083 -0.028,0.089 0.099,0.144 -0.153,0.201 0.006,0.251 -0.182,0.297 0.278,-0.122 0.103,-0.193 -0.053,-0.109 0.12,-0.216 0.187,-0.103 -0.074,-0.163 0.005,-0.129 0.229,0.048 0.113,-0.005 0.09,-0.051 0.165,-0.02 0.033,0.144 0.222,-0.018 -0.081,0.182 -0.169,0.211 -0.04,0.128 -0.271,0.213 -0.181,0.091 0.279,0.023 0.408,-0.285 0.242,-0.251 -0.007,0.314 -0.197,0.282 -0.168,0.178 -0.19,0.056 -0.189,0.145 -0.092,0.237 0.011,0.158 0.054,0.125 0.193,0.211 -0.217,0.408 0.242,-0.051 0.132,0.077 0.186,0.235 -0.112,0.272 -0.078,0.139 -0.472,0.575 -0.206,0.292 -0.241,0.187 0.003,0.307 -0.138,0.224 -0.704,0.769 -0.123,0.167 -0.555,1.229 -0.354,0.518 -0.203,0.177 -0.215,0.143 -0.515,0.245 -0.228,0.282 -0.251,0.234 -0.265,0.053 0.008,0.104 0.17,0.058 0.133,0.154 -0.099,0.173 -0.189,0.108 -0.196,0.031 -0.1,0.111 0.468,-0.079 0.132,0.09 0.024,0.191 0.05,0.172 0.113,0.228 0.394,0.146 0.354,0.068 0.069,0.106 0.053,0.365 -0.064,0.179 -0.079,0.118 -0.119,0.042 -0.288,0.023 -0.289,-0.083 -0.191,-0.221 -0.547,0.071 -0.146,0.047 -0.075,-0.04 0.303,-0.232 -0.158,-0.132 -0.132,-0.049 -0.143,0.077 -0.096,0.122 -0.028,0.2 -0.099,0.116 -0.15,0.033 -0.213,-0.167 -0.211,-0.238 -0.31,-0.24 0.048,0.148 0.238,0.363 0.119,0.241 -0.277,0.193 -0.29,0.15 -0.244,0.088 -0.23,0.138 -0.271,0.215 -0.149,0.076 -0.396,0.005 -0.212,0.068 -0.07,0.284 -0.148,0.181 -0.348,0.036 0.126,0.057 0.077,0.091 -0.23,0.858 -0.05,0.357 -0.043,0.612 -0.145,0.57 -0.413,-0.003 0.066,0.101 0.313,0.161 -0.059,0.243 -0.344,0.445 -0.144,0.257 -0.14,0.626 -0.21,0.579 -0.321,0.66 -0.003,0.119 0.113,0.169 0.137,0.146 0.008,0.206 -0.042,0.109 -0.153,0.028 -0.134,0.071 -0.716,0.182 -0.234,0.204 -0.193,0.366 -0.226,0.316 -0.752,0.702 -0.442,0.59 -0.089,0.169 -0.119,0.123 -0.967,0.28 -0.684,0.042 -0.372,-0.072 -0.359,-0.142 -0.199,-0.048 -0.38,0.087 -0.166,0.095 -0.298,-0.094 -0.236,0.071 -0.07,-0.069 -0.088,-0.173 0.049,-0.23 -0.065,-0.17 -0.15,-0.115 -0.101,-0.134 -0.115,-0.095 -0.314,-0.037 -0.496,0.06 -0.164,-0.006 -0.337,-0.563 -0.111,-0.138 -0.401,-0.179 -0.137,0.025 -0.215,0.3 -0.127,0.051 -0.754,0.032 -0.756,-0.097 -0.278,-0.112 -0.055,-0.259 0.574,-0.711 -0.17,0.095 -0.354,0.289 -0.226,-0.044 0.217,-0.315 0.019,-0.141 -0.045,-0.156 -0.295,0.265 -0.336,0.035 -0.043,-0.246 0.03,-0.285 0.068,-0.081 0.907,-0.149 0.327,-0.097 0.143,-0.153 -0.543,-0.052 -0.034,-0.214 0.078,-0.171 0.464,-0.284 -0.342,0.072 -0.379,-0.025 0.025,-0.3 0.099,-0.234 0.397,-0.007 -0.124,-0.161 -0.019,-0.224 0.11,-0.015 0.403,0.302 0.291,0.11 -0.123,-0.227 0.017,-0.143 0.077,-0.064 0.238,-0.045 -0.066,-0.04 -0.223,-0.058 -0.266,-0.172 -0.028,-0.182 0.01,-0.21 0.286,-0.289 0.169,0.172 0.2,-0.047 -0.153,-0.135 -0.093,-0.202 0.063,-0.133 0.607,-0.535 0.155,0.515 0.036,-0.171 0.009,-0.162 -0.073,-0.141 0.011,-0.142 0.07,-0.122 0.26,-0.121 0.338,-0.392 0.25,-0.182 0.203,0.117 0.139,0.157 -0.021,-0.156 -0.099,-0.129 -0.027,-0.359 0.454,-0.556 0.499,-0.528 0.479,-0.552 0.255,-0.2 0.543,-0.227 0.348,0.095 0.089,-0.018 0.516,-0.396 0.214,-0.103 0.195,0.141 0.12,0.051 -0.121,-0.362 0.095,-0.166 0.431,-0.292 0.54,-0.301 0.41,-0.125 0.302,-0.204 0.182,-0.005 -0.027,-0.154 0.031,-0.147 0.156,0.01 0.048,-0.058 -0.138,-0.08 0.445,-0.294 0.242,-0.325 0.126,-0.067 0.115,-0.098 0.142,-0.224 0.168,-0.074 0.156,0.035 0.113,0.11 -0.062,-0.183 -0.2,-0.104 0.215,-0.158 0.223,-0.11 0.217,0.079 0.213,0.128 -0.213,-0.196 -0.035,-0.121 0.259,-0.14 0.14,-0.043 0.196,0.262 -0.028,-0.208 0.046,-0.184 0.277,-0.301 0.363,-0.496 0.116,0.173 0.019,0.209 -0.018,0.253 0.075,-0.087 0.025,-0.229 -0.056,-0.403 0.454,-0.743 0.09,-0.083 0.1,-0.05 0.158,-0.02 -0.049,-0.112 -0.123,-0.108 0.124,-0.376 0.074,-0.429 0.105,-0.412 0.169,-0.402 0.185,-0.67 0.141,-0.14 0.381,-0.048 0.167,-0.094 0.278,-0.241 0.329,-0.436 0.176,-0.351 0.231,-0.905 0.13,-0.943 0.374,-0.697 0.549,-0.503 0.483,-0.382 0.198,-0.08 0.334,-0.024 0.318,0.105 -0.592,0.092 -0.061,0.227 -0.019,0.23 0.068,0.206 0.106,0.184 0.287,0.173 0.336,0.103 0.15,0.39 0.027,0.463 0.046,0.398 0.136,0.349 z m 2.243,-1.541 -0.376,0.215 0.016,-0.149 0.073,-0.325 0.171,-0.164 0.084,-0.011 0.172,-0.123 -0.019,0.272 -0.121,0.285 z m -19.464,16.519 0.121,0.477 -0.257,-0.091 -0.107,-0.145 0.196,-0.239 0.047,-0.002 z m -0.654,1.898 -0.015,0.197 -0.033,0.099 -0.098,10e-4 -0.146,-0.022 -0.143,-0.091 -0.092,0.026 -0.076,-0.033 0.099,-0.222 0.333,-0.118 0.128,0.095 0.043,0.068 z m 3.925,4.881 0.002,0.163 -0.293,-0.058 0.006,0.183 0.231,0.097 0.085,0.132 0.24,-0.038 0.054,0.197 -0.056,0.177 -0.16,0.129 -0.474,0.065 -0.308,0.257 -0.266,-0.039 -0.072,0.023 -0.305,0.276 -0.341,0.085 -0.093,-0.021 0.047,-0.246 0.254,-0.233 0.005,-0.224 0.065,-0.179 0.243,-0.126 0.004,-0.232 0.164,-0.207 -0.1,-0.445 0.053,-0.399 0.482,-0.022 0.533,0.685 z m -5.399,16.581 0.061,0.373 -0.154,0.001 -0.321,-0.104 -0.101,-0.159 -0.068,-0.039 -0.117,0.185 -0.188,0.009 -0.042,-0.062 0.074,-0.197 0.443,-0.372 0.083,-0.467 -0.006,-0.15 0.348,-0.035 0.082,0.057 0.037,0.064 -0.022,0.082 -0.141,0.154 -0.005,0.178 0.036,0.186 -0.115,0.09 0.06,0.16 0.056,0.046 z m 8.299,7.828 0.155,0.234 -0.298,0.102 -0.145,-0.085 -0.102,-0.107 -0.051,-0.151 0.161,0.016 0.139,-0.063 0.141,0.054 z"
     title="New Zealand"
     id="NZ" />

</svg>



Note: in case it isn't obvious: I've reduced the map to two countries so it will fit in a code snippet.
